# Increasing font size makes coloring of last table column incomplete

Tags: tables, color

My table is aligned to the left by using `\hskip-1.50cm`. When I increase the font size from `10pt` to `12pt`, the table's layout shifts to the right and understandably so. The alternating rowcolors do not completely fill up the last column. Is there an easy way to fix this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\newcommand*{\thead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries #1}}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{2}{gray!10}{orange!5}
\hskip-1.50cm
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | p{2cm} | }

\thead{Degree} & \thead{Institution} & \thead{Year of Graduation} & \thead{Distinction} \\ \hline
Degree1 &  Longer University1 &  year1 & Long Distinction1 \\ \hline

Degree2 (sub1) &  LongName University2 &  year2 & Distinction2 \\ \hline

Degree3 (sub3, sub4) &  LongerName University3 &  year3 & Distinction3 \\ \hline

Degree4 (subject1, subject2) &  LongestName University4 &  year4 & Distinction4 \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the font size from 10 to 12 pt increases the widths of the unbreakable header cells, in the process making the entire table wider than the text block. I suggest you use a `tabularx` environment instead of `tabular` and allow line breaks in all four columns.

Since you're using alternating colors to provide visual distinctions between rows, you can dispense with the `\hline` instructions. You can also remove the vertical bars.

Use `\noindent` to left-align the tabular material; this without having to know the current value of `\parindent`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\begin{document}

\rowcolors{2}{gray!10}{orange!5}
\noindent    
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ LCCC  }
\textbf{Degree} & \textbf{Institution} & \textbf{Year of Graduation} & \textbf{Distinction} \\
Degree1 &  Longer University1 &  year1 & Long Distinction1 \\
Degree2 (sub1) &  LongName University2 &  year2 & Distinction2 \\
Degree3 (sub3, sub4) &  LongerName University3 &  year3 & Distinction3 \\
Degree4 (subject1, subject2) &  LongestName University4 &  year4 & Distinction4 \\ 
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```